# Не запускается код который был написан на python 2.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, инспекция-кода, python-2.7

Всем добрый день помогите запустить этот код(2d моделирование), препод дал задание сделать gui, но после запуска программы выходит такая форма[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но чтоб началась само моделирование надо закрыть форму и вот тут начинается вся беда, начинается открываться несколько форм и выходит такая ошибка:

> RuntimeWarning: More than 20 figures have been opened. Figures created through the pyplot interface (`matplotlib.pyplot.figure`) are retained until explicitly closed and may consume too much memory. (To control this warning, see the rcParam `figure.max_open_warning`).
> fig = plt.figure()
>
> line 309, in 
> plt.show(1)
>
> line 353, in show
> return _backend_mod.show(*args, **kwargs)
> TypeError: show() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Пожалуйста помогите решить эту проблему, так как в питоне я вообще новичок и не понимаю, как решить эту проблему. У самого питон 3.9 и пишу код в pycharm'е. У препода все работает, но у него питон 2.7 стоит. Возможно ли вообще запустить такой код на 3.9?

```
#import idlelib.PyShell
#import sys
import time
import pylab
import numpy as np
#import sys, idlelib.PyShell; idlelib.PyShell.warning_stream = sys.stderr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

#idlelib.PyShell.warning_stream = sys.stderr

N1 = 40
tt =3.0
l = 2.00
h = l/N1
N2 = 50
t=tt/N2
t2=t/2.0
hh=h*h
#rr=hh/t2
rr=hh/t

a11=0.03
a12=0.01
p1=-0.05
a21=0.03
a22=0.01
p2=-0.03
q1=0.0
q2=0.0

m1=0.95
m2=1.2
d1=0.7
d2=0.5
c1=0.25
c2=0.65
h1=0.55
b1=0.1

def e1(u,v):
    return a11+a12*u*v
def e2(u,v):
    return a21+a22*u*v

def f1(u,v):
    return u*(m1-d1)+v*d1-c1*u*u-h1*u-b1
def f2(u,v):
    return v*(m2-d2)+u*d2-c2*v*v

def Rs(x,y):
    return 4
    #return 2.*np.sin(np.pi*y/3.)+0.3*np.sin(3*np.pi*y/3.)*np.sin(2.*np.pi*y/3.)+np.sin(np.pi*x/2.)
    #return 2.*np.sin((np.pi*y/3.)+0.2)+0.8*np.sin((3.*np.pi*y/3.)+1.0)*np.sin((1.*np.pi*y/3.)+2.0)+np.sin(np.pi*x/2.)
    #return 2.*np.sin((np.pi*y/3.)+0.5)+0.8*np.sin((3.*np.pi*y/3.))*np.sin((1.*np.pi*y/3.)+2.)+np.sin(np.pi*x/2.)
    #return np.exp((y/2)*np.sin(3.*np.pi*y/2.)) * np.sin((1.*np.pi*x/3.)+0.1)

def y_0(x,y):
    return 1.5 * np.exp(-30.0*(((x/1.8)-0.55)**2 + (y-0.35)**2))
def v_0(x,y):
    return 1.5 * np.exp(-15.0*(((x/2.0)-0.5)**2 + (y-1.35)**2))

x1 = np.zeros((N1+1), 'float')
x2 = np.zeros((N1+1), 'float')
y = np.zeros((N1+1, N1+1), 'float')
y0 = np.zeros((N1+1, N1+1), 'float')
v = np.zeros((N1+1, N1+1), 'float')
v0 = np.zeros((N1+1, N1+1), 'float')
a = np.zeros((N1+1), 'float')
b = np.zeros((N1+1), 'float')
z = np.zeros((N1+1), 'float')
R = np.zeros((N1+1, N1+1), 'float')

#Computation of y,v
tst = time.clock()

for i1 in range(0,N1+1):
    x1[i1]=i1*h
for i2 in range(0,N1+1):
    x2[i2]=i2*h

#for i2 in range(0,N1+1):
    #for i1 in range(0,N1+1):
        #if i2*h<0.62: y[i1,i2] = 0.0
        #elif i2*h<1.27: y[i1,i2]=-21.30*(i2*h)*(i2*h)+40.26*(i2*h)-16.77
        #else: y[i1,i2]=0.0
        #if i2*h<1.32: v[i1,i2] = 0.0
        #elif i2*h<1.96: v[i1,i2]=-21.30*(i2*h)*(i2*h)+69.65*(i2*h)-54.69
        #else: v[i1,i2]=0.0

for i1 in range(0, N1+1):
    for i2 in range(0, N1+1):
        y0[i1, i2] = y_0(x1[i1], x2[i2])
        v0[i1, i2] = v_0(x1[i1], x2[i2])
        R[i1, i2] = Rs(x1[i1], x2[i2])
        y[i1, i2] = y0[i1, i2]
        v[i1, i2] = v0[i1, i2]

fig = plt.figure()
#ax = Axes3D(fig)
x1 = np.linspace(0., l, N1+1)
x2 = np.linspace(0., l, N1+1)
X1,X2 = np.meshgrid(x1, x2)
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
#ax.plot_surface(X1, X2, y0, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap='Blues')
#ax.plot_surface(X1, X2, v0, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap='BuGn')
#ax.plot_wireframe(X1, X2, R, rstride=1, cstride=1)
#ax.plot_surface(X1, X2, R, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap='summer')

          #Liniya urovnya ('ax' turn off before activation)

g = np.linspace(0., 2., 21)
#plt.clabel(plt.contour(x1,x2,y0,g,colors='gray'), inline=True, fontsize=8)
#plt.contourf(x1,x2,y0,g,cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
plt.clabel(plt.contour(x1,x2,v0,g,colors='gray'), inline=True, fontsize=8)
plt.contourf(x1,x2,v0,g,cmap=plt.cm.BuGn)
plt.colorbar()

plt.show()
pylab.ion()

for j in range(1,N2+1):

# y[k+1/2] to x1
    for i2 in range(0,N1+1):
        #a[0]=0.
        #b[0]=0.
        e210 = e1((y[1,i2]+y[0,i2])/2.00,(v[1,i2]+v[0,i2])/2.00)
        a[0] = e210/(e210+rr/2.0)
        FD0 = (-p1/rr)*(y[1,i2]+y[0,i2])*(v[1,i2]-v[0,i2])- \
              (q1/rr)*(y[1,i2]+y[0,i2])*(R[1,i2]-R[0,i2])+f1(y[0,i2],v[0,i2])*t2
        b[0] = (y[0,i2]+FD0)/(1+2.0*e210/rr)

        for i1 in range(1,N1):
            e11 = e1((y[i1,i2]+y[i1-1,i2])/2.00,(v[i1,i2]+v[i1-1,i2])/2.00)
            e12 = e1((y[i1,i2]+y[i1+1,i2])/2.00,(v[i1,i2]+v[i1+1,i2])/2.00)
            aa = e11/rr
            bb = e12/rr
            cc = aa+bb+1
            a[i1] = bb/(cc-aa*a[i1-1])

            r11 = (1.0/rr)*(y[i1,i2]+y[i1-1,i2])/2.00
            r12 = (1.0/rr)*(y[i1,i2]+y[i1+1,i2])/2.00

            L1v = p1*(r12*(v[i1+1,i2]-v[i1,i2]) - r11*(v[i1,i2]-v[i1-1,i2]))
            L1R = q1*(r12*(R[i1+1,i2]-R[i1,i2]) - r11*(R[i1,i2]-R[i1-1,i2]))

            d = y[i1,i2] + f1(y[i1,i2],v[i1,i2])*t2 - L1v - L1R
            b[i1]=(aa*b[i1-1]+d)/(cc-aa*a[i1-1])
        #y[N1,i2]=b[N1-1]/(1-a[N1-1])
        #y[N1,i2]=0.
        e22n = e1((y[N1,i2]+y[N1-1,i2])/2.00,(v[N1,i2]+v[N1-1,i2])/2.00)
        FDn = p1*(y[N1,i2]+y[N1-1,i2])*(v[N1,i2]-v[N1-1,i2])/2.0 + \
              q1*(y[N1,i2]+y[N1-1,i2])*(R[N1,i2]-R[N1-1,i2])/2.0 + \
              f1(y[N1,i2],v[N1,i2])*hh/4.0
        y[N1,i2]=(e22n*b[N1-1] + rr*y[N1,i2]/2.0 + FDn)/(e22n*(1-a[N1-1])+rr/2.0)
        for ii in range(1,N1+1):
            i1=N1-ii
            y[i1,i2] = a[i1]*y[i1+1,i2]+b[i1]

# v[k+1/2] to x1
        e210 = e1((y[1,i2]+y[0,i2])/2.00,(v[1,i2]+v[0,i2])/2.00)
        a[0] = e210/(e210+rr/2.0)
        FD0 = (-p2/rr)*(v[1,i2]+v[0,i2])*(y[1,i2]-y[0,i2])- \
              (q2/rr)*(v[1,i2]+v[0,i2])*(R[1,i2]-R[0,i2])+f2(y[0,i2],v[0,i2])*t2
        b[0] = (v[0,i2]+FD0)/(1+2.0*e210/rr)
        for i1 in range(1,N1):
            e21=e2((y[i1,i2]+y[i1-1,i2])/2.00,(v[i1,i2]+v[i1-1,i2])/2.00)
            e22=e2((y[i1,i2]+y[i1+1,i2])/2.00,(v[i1,i2]+v[i1+1,i2])/2.00)
            aa = e21/rr
            bb = e22/rr
            cc = aa+bb+1
            a[i1] = bb/(cc-aa*a[i1-1])

            r11 = (1.0/rr)*(v[i1,i2]+v[i1-1,i2])/2.
            r12 = (1.0/rr)*(v[i1,i2]+v[i1+1,i2])/2.

            L1y = p2*(r12*(y[i1+1,i2]-y[i1,i2]) - r11*(y[i1,i2]-y[i1-1,i2]))
            L1R = q2*(r12*(R[i1+1,i2]-R[i1,i2]) - r11*(R[i1,i2]-R[i1-1,i2]))

            d = v[i1,i2] + f2(y[i1,i2],v[i1,i2])*t2 - L1y - L1R
            b[i1]=(aa*b[i1-1]+d)/(cc-aa*a[i1-1])
        #v[N1,i2]=b[N1-1]/(1-a[N1-1])
        #v[N1,i2]=0.
        e22n = e2((y[N1,i2]+y[N1-1,i2])/2.00,(v[N1,i2]+v[N1-1,i2])/2.00)
        FDn = p2*(v[N1,i2]+v[N1-1,i2])*(y[N1,i2]-y[N1-1,i2])/2.0 + \
              q2*(v[N1,i2]+v[N1-1,i2])*(R[N1,i2]-R[N1-1,i2])/2.0 + \
              f2(y[N1,i2],v[N1,i2])*hh/4.0
        v[N1,i2]=(e22n*b[N1-1] + rr*v[N1,i2]/2.0 + FDn)/(e22n*(1-a[N1-1])+rr/2.0)

        for ii in range(1,N1+1):
            i1=N1-ii
            v[i1,i2] = a[i1]*v[i1+1,i2]+b[i1]

# y[k+1] to x2
    for i1 in range(0,N1+1):
        a[0]=0.
        b[0]=0.
        #e210 = e1((y[i1,1]+y[i1,0])/2.00,(v[i1,1]+v[i1,0])/2.00)
        #FD0 = (-p1/rr)*(y[i1,1]+y[i1,0])*(v[i1,1]-v[i1,0])- \
        #      (q1/rr)*(y[i1,1]+y[i1,0])*(R[i1,1]-R[i1,0])+f1(y[i1,0],v[i1,0])*t2
        #b[0] = (y[i1,0]+FD0)/(1+2.0*e210/rr)

        for i2 in range(1,N1):
            e21 = e1((y[i1,i2]+y[i1,i2-1])/2.00,(v[i1,i2]+v[i1,i2-1])/2.00)
            e22 = e1((y[i1,i2]+y[i1,i2+1])/2.00,(v[i1,i2]+v[i1,i2+1])/2.00)
            aa = e21/rr
            bb = e22/rr
            cc = aa+bb+1
            a[i2] = bb/(cc-aa*a[i2-1])

            r21 = (1.0/rr)*(y[i1,i2]+y[i1,i2-1])/2.
            r22 = (1.0/rr)*(y[i1,i2]+y[i1,i2+1])/2.

            L2v = p1*(r22*(v[i1,i2+1]-v[i1,i2]) - r21*(v[i1,i2]-v[i1,i2-1]))
            L2R = q1*(r22*(R[i1,i2+1]-R[i1,i2]) - r21*(R[i1,i2]-R[i1,i2-1]))

            d = y[i1,i2] + f1(y[i1,i2],v[i1,i2])*t2 - L2v - L2R
            b[i2]=(aa*b[i2-1]+d)/(cc-aa*a[i2-1])
        y[i1,N1]=0.
        #e22n = e1((y[i1,N1]+y[i1,N1-1])/2.00,(v[i1,N1]+v[i1,N1-1])/2.00)
        #FDn = p1*(y[i1,N1]+y[i1,N1-1])*(v[i1,N1]-v[i1,N1-1])/2.0 + \
        #      q1*(y[i1,N1]+y[i1,N1-1])*(R[i1,N1]-R[i1,N1-1])/2.0 + \
        #      f1(y[i1,N1],v[i1,N1])*hh/4.0
        #y[i1,N1]=(e22n*b[N1-1] + rr*y[i1,N1]/2.0 + FDn)/(e22n*(1-a[N1-1])+rr/2.0)

        for ii in range(1,N1+1):
            i2=N1-ii
            y[i1,i2] = a[i2]*y[i1,i2+1]+b[i2]

        for i2 in range(0,N1+1):
            if y[i1,i2]<0: y[i1,i2]=0.0

# v[k+1] to x2
        #e210 = e2((y[i1,1]+y[i1,0])/2.00,(v[i1,1]+v[i1,0])/2.00)
        #a[0] = e210/(e210+rr/2.0)
        #FD0 = (-p2/rr)*(v[i1,1]+v[i1,0])*(y[i1,1]-y[i1,0])- \
        #      (q2/rr)*(v[i1,1]+v[i1,0])*(R[i1,1]-R[i1,0])+f2(y[i1,0],v[i1,0])*t2
        #b[0] = (v[i1,0]+FD0)/(1+2.0*e210/rr)

        for i2 in range(1,N1):
            e21=e2((y[i1,i2]+y[i1,i2-1])/2.00,(v[i1,i2]+v[i1,i2-1])/2.00)
            e22=e2((y[i1,i2]+y[i1,i2+1])/2.00,(v[i1,i2]+v[i1,i2+1])/2.00)
            aa = e21/rr
            bb = e22/rr
            cc = aa+bb+1
            a[i2] = bb/(cc-aa*a[i2-1])

            r21 = (1.0/rr)*(v[i1,i2]+v[i1,i2-1])/2.
            r22 = (1.0/rr)*(v[i1,i2]+v[i1,i2+1])/2.

            L2y = p2*(r22*(y[i1,i2+1]-y[i1,i2])-r21*(y[i1,i2]-y[i1,i2-1]))
            L2R = q2*(r22*(R[i1,i2+1]-R[i1,i2])-r21*(R[i1,i2]-R[i1,i2-1]))

            d = v[i1,i2] + f2(y[i1,i2],v[i1,i2])*t2 - L2y - L2R
            b[i2]=(aa*b[i2-1]+d)/(cc-aa*a[i2-1])
        v[i1,N1]=0.
        #e22n = e2((y[i1,N1]+y[i1,N1-1])/2.00,(v[i1,N1]+v[i1,N1-1])/2.00)
        #FDn = p2*(v[i1,N1]+v[i1,N1-1])*(y[i1,N1]-y[i1,N1-1])/2.0 + \
        #      q2*(v[i1,N1]+v[i1,N1-1])*(R[i1,N1]-R[i1,N1-1])/2.0 + \
        #      f2(y[i1,N1],v[i1,N1])*hh/4.0
        #v[i1,N1]=(e22n*b[N1-1] + rr*v[i1,N1]/2.0 + FDn)/(e22n*(1-a[N1-1])+rr/2.0)

        for ii in range(1,N1+1):
            i2=N1-ii
            v[i1,i2] = a[i2]*v[i1,i2+1]+b[i2]

        for i2 in range(0,N1+1):
            if v[i1,i2]<0: v[i1,i2]=0.0
#graphics
    pylab.clf()
    x1 = np.linspace(0., l, N1+1)
    x2 = np.linspace(0., l, N1+1)
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = Axes3D(fig)
    X1, X2 = np.meshgrid(x1, x2)
    plt.xlabel('X')
    plt.ylabel('Y')
    ax.plot_surface(X1, X2, y, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap='Blues')
    ax.plot_surface(X1, X2, v, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap='BuGn')
    #ax.plot_wireframe(X1, X2, y, rstride=1, cstride=1)
    #plt.contourf(XX1, XX2, y, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
    #plt.colorbar()
    #plt.show()
    pylab.draw()

fig = plt.figure()
#ax = Axes3D(fig)
x1 = np.linspace(0., l, N1+1)
x2 = np.linspace(0., l, N1+1)
X1,X2 = np.meshgrid(x1, x2)
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
#ax.plot_surface(X1, X2, y, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap='Blues')
#ax.plot_surface(X1, X2, v, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap='BuGn')

          #Liniya urovnya ('ax' turn off before activation)

g = np.linspace(0., 2.0, 21)
plt.clabel(plt.contour(x1,x2,y,g,colors='gray'), inline=True, fontsize=8)
plt.contourf(x1,x2,y,g,cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
#plt.clabel(plt.contour(x1,x2,v,g,colors='gray'), inline=True, fontsize=8)
#plt.contourf(x1,x2,v,g,cmap=plt.cm.BuGn)
plt.colorbar()

plt.show()
plt.show(1)
f1 = open('rezy.txt','w')
for i in range(0,N1+1):
    for j in range(0,N1+1):
        f1.write("%f\n" % y[i,j])
f1.close()
f2 = open('rezv.txt','w')
for i in range(0,N1+1):
    for j in range(0,N1+1):
        f2.write("%f\n" % v[i,j])
    f2.write("\n") 
f2.close()

dt = time.clock() - tst
print "N2 = %i, N1 = %i, time solution = %1.3e, h = %1.3e" % (N2, N1, dt, h)
```

Comment: Это не ошибка, это предупреждение. Вообще сколько графиков должно выйти? Я в Google Colab в итоге вижу 3 картинки - ту и ещё две потом. Просто надо подождать потом ещё.

Comment: @CrazyElf Может в Colab'е старый питон? Я у себя на 3.7 действительно вижу мельтишение окон. И потом, я думаю, там фишка в показе анимации, а не конечной картинке. А иначе зачем там рисование во внешнем цикле.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот, поковырял чутка. Какую-то анимацию роста горбиков показывает. Python 3.7.4 под Windows 7. И Python 3.9.0 под Windows 10.

```
#import idlelib.PyShell
#import sys
import time
#import pylab
import numpy as np
#import sys, idlelib.PyShell; idlelib.PyShell.warning_stream = sys.stderr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

#idlelib.PyShell.warning_stream = sys.stderr

N1 = 40
tt =3.0
l = 2.00
h = l/N1
N2 = 50
t=tt/N2
t2=t/2.0
hh=h*h
#rr=hh/t2
rr=hh/t

a11=0.03
a12=0.01
p1=-0.05
a21=0.03
a22=0.01
p2=-0.03
q1=0.0
q2=0.0

m1=0.95
m2=1.2
d1=0.7
d2=0.5
c1=0.25
c2=0.65
h1=0.55
b1=0.1

def e1(u,v):
    return a11+a12*u*v
def e2(u,v):
    return a21+a22*u*v

def f1(u,v):
    return u*(m1-d1)+v*d1-c1*u*u-h1*u-b1
def f2(u,v):
    return v*(m2-d2)+u*d2-c2*v*v

def Rs(x,y):
    return 4
    #return 2.*np.sin(np.pi*y/3.)+0.3*np.sin(3*np.pi*y/3.)*np.sin(2.*np.pi*y/3.)+np.sin(np.pi*x/2.)
    #return 2.*np.sin((np.pi*y/3.)+0.2)+0.8*np.sin((3.*np.pi*y/3.)+1.0)*np.sin((1.*np.pi*y/3.)+2.0)+np.sin(np.pi*x/2.)
    #return 2.*np.sin((np.pi*y/3.)+0.5)+0.8*np.sin((3.*np.pi*y/3.))*np.sin((1.*np.pi*y/3.)+2.)+np.sin(np.pi*x/2.)
    #return np.exp((y/2)*np.sin(3.*np.pi*y/2.)) * np.sin((1.*np.pi*x/3.)+0.1)

def y_0(x,y):
    return 1.5 * np.exp(-30.0*(((x/1.8)-0.55)**2 + (y-0.35)**2))
def v_0(x,y):
    return 1.5 * np.exp(-15.0*(((x/2.0)-0.5)**2 + (y-1.35)**2))

x1 = np.zeros((N1+1), 'float')
x2 = np.zeros((N1+1), 'float')
y = np.zeros((N1+1, N1+1), 'float')
y0 = np.zeros((N1+1, N1+1), 'float')
v = np.zeros((N1+1, N1+1), 'float')
v0 = np.zeros((N1+1, N1+1), 'float')
a = np.zeros((N1+1), 'float')
b = np.zeros((N1+1), 'float')
z = np.zeros((N1+1), 'float')
R = np.zeros((N1+1, N1+1), 'float')

#Computation of y,v
tst = time.perf_counter()

for i1 in range(0,N1+1):
    x1[i1]=i1*h
for i2 in range(0,N1+1):
    x2[i2]=i2*h

#for i2 in range(0,N1+1):
    #for i1 in range(0,N1+1):
        #if i2*h<0.62: y[i1,i2] = 0.0
        #elif i2*h<1.27: y[i1,i2]=-21.30*(i2*h)*(i2*h)+40.26*(i2*h)-16.77
        #else: y[i1,i2]=0.0
        #if i2*h<1.32: v[i1,i2] = 0.0
        #elif i2*h<1.96: v[i1,i2]=-21.30*(i2*h)*(i2*h)+69.65*(i2*h)-54.69
        #else: v[i1,i2]=0.0

for i1 in range(0, N1+1):
    for i2 in range(0, N1+1):
        y0[i1, i2] = y_0(x1[i1], x2[i2])
        v0[i1, i2] = v_0(x1[i1], x2[i2])
        R[i1, i2] = Rs(x1[i1], x2[i2])
        y[i1, i2] = y0[i1, i2]
        v[i1, i2] = v0[i1, i2]

fig = plt.figure()
x1 = np.linspace(0., l, N1+1)
x2 = np.linspace(0., l, N1+1)
X1,X2 = np.meshgrid(x1, x2)
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
#ax.plot_surface(X1, X2, y0, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap='Blues')
#ax.plot_surface(X1, X2, v0, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap='BuGn')
#ax.plot_wireframe(X1, X2, R, rstride=1, cstride=1)
#ax.plot_surface(X1, X2, R, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap='summer')

          #Liniya urovnya ('ax' turn off before activation)

g = np.linspace(0., 2., 21)
plt.clabel(plt.contour(x1,x2,y0,g,colors='gray'), inline=True, fontsize=8)
plt.contourf(x1,x2,y0,g,cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
plt.clabel(plt.contour(x1,x2,v0,g,colors='gray'), inline=True, fontsize=8)
plt.contourf(x1,x2,v0,g,cmap=plt.cm.BuGn)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
plt.ion()
fig = plt.figure()


for j in range(1,N2+1):

# y[k+1/2] to x1
    for i2 in range(0,N1+1):
        #a[0]=0.
        #b[0]=0.
        e210 = e1((y[1,i2]+y[0,i2])/2.00,(v[1,i2]+v[0,i2])/2.00)
        a[0] = e210/(e210+rr/2.0)
        FD0 = (-p1/rr)*(y[1,i2]+y[0,i2])*(v[1,i2]-v[0,i2])- \
              (q1/rr)*(y[1,i2]+y[0,i2])*(R[1,i2]-R[0,i2])+f1(y[0,i2],v[0,i2])*t2
        b[0] = (y[0,i2]+FD0)/(1+2.0*e210/rr)

        for i1 in range(1,N1):
            e11 = e1((y[i1,i2]+y[i1-1,i2])/2.00,(v[i1,i2]+v[i1-1,i2])/2.00)
            e12 = e1((y[i1,i2]+y[i1+1,i2])/2.00,(v[i1,i2]+v[i1+1,i2])/2.00)
            aa = e11/rr
            bb = e12/rr
            cc = aa+bb+1
            a[i1] = bb/(cc-aa*a[i1-1])

            r11 = (1.0/rr)*(y[i1,i2]+y[i1-1,i2])/2.00
            r12 = (1.0/rr)*(y[i1,i2]+y[i1+1,i2])/2.00

            L1v = p1*(r12*(v[i1+1,i2]-v[i1,i2]) - r11*(v[i1,i2]-v[i1-1,i2]))
            L1R = q1*(r12*(R[i1+1,i2]-R[i1,i2]) - r11*(R[i1,i2]-R[i1-1,i2]))

            d = y[i1,i2] + f1(y[i1,i2],v[i1,i2])*t2 - L1v - L1R
            b[i1]=(aa*b[i1-1]+d)/(cc-aa*a[i1-1])
        #y[N1,i2]=b[N1-1]/(1-a[N1-1])
        #y[N1,i2]=0.
        e22n = e1((y[N1,i2]+y[N1-1,i2])/2.00,(v[N1,i2]+v[N1-1,i2])/2.00)
        FDn = p1*(y[N1,i2]+y[N1-1,i2])*(v[N1,i2]-v[N1-1,i2])/2.0 + \
              q1*(y[N1,i2]+y[N1-1,i2])*(R[N1,i2]-R[N1-1,i2])/2.0 + \
              f1(y[N1,i2],v[N1,i2])*hh/4.0
        y[N1,i2]=(e22n*b[N1-1] + rr*y[N1,i2]/2.0 + FDn)/(e22n*(1-a[N1-1])+rr/2.0)
        for ii in range(1,N1+1):
            i1=N1-ii
            y[i1,i2] = a[i1]*y[i1+1,i2]+b[i1]

# v[k+1/2] to x1
        e210 = e1((y[1,i2]+y[0,i2])/2.00,(v[1,i2]+v[0,i2])/2.00)
        a[0] = e210/(e210+rr/2.0)
        FD0 = (-p2/rr)*(v[1,i2]+v[0,i2])*(y[1,i2]-y[0,i2])- \
              (q2/rr)*(v[1,i2]+v[0,i2])*(R[1,i2]-R[0,i2])+f2(y[0,i2],v[0,i2])*t2
        b[0] = (v[0,i2]+FD0)/(1+2.0*e210/rr)
        for i1 in range(1,N1):
            e21=e2((y[i1,i2]+y[i1-1,i2])/2.00,(v[i1,i2]+v[i1-1,i2])/2.00)
            e22=e2((y[i1,i2]+y[i1+1,i2])/2.00,(v[i1,i2]+v[i1+1,i2])/2.00)
            aa = e21/rr
            bb = e22/rr
            cc = aa+bb+1
            a[i1] = bb/(cc-aa*a[i1-1])

            r11 = (1.0/rr)*(v[i1,i2]+v[i1-1,i2])/2.
            r12 = (1.0/rr)*(v[i1,i2]+v[i1+1,i2])/2.

            L1y = p2*(r12*(y[i1+1,i2]-y[i1,i2]) - r11*(y[i1,i2]-y[i1-1,i2]))
            L1R = q2*(r12*(R[i1+1,i2]-R[i1,i2]) - r11*(R[i1,i2]-R[i1-1,i2]))

            d = v[i1,i2] + f2(y[i1,i2],v[i1,i2])*t2 - L1y - L1R
            b[i1]=(aa*b[i1-1]+d)/(cc-aa*a[i1-1])
        #v[N1,i2]=b[N1-1]/(1-a[N1-1])
        #v[N1,i2]=0.
        e22n = e2((y[N1,i2]+y[N1-1,i2])/2.00,(v[N1,i2]+v[N1-1,i2])/2.00)
        FDn = p2*(v[N1,i2]+v[N1-1,i2])*(y[N1,i2]-y[N1-1,i2])/2.0 + \
              q2*(v[N1,i2]+v[N1-1,i2])*(R[N1,i2]-R[N1-1,i2])/2.0 + \
              f2(y[N1,i2],v[N1,i2])*hh/4.0
        v[N1,i2]=(e22n*b[N1-1] + rr*v[N1,i2]/2.0 + FDn)/(e22n*(1-a[N1-1])+rr/2.0)

        for ii in range(1,N1+1):
            i1=N1-ii
            v[i1,i2] = a[i1]*v[i1+1,i2]+b[i1]

# y[k+1] to x2
    for i1 in range(0,N1+1):
        a[0]=0.
        b[0]=0.
        #e210 = e1((y[i1,1]+y[i1,0])/2.00,(v[i1,1]+v[i1,0])/2.00)
        #FD0 = (-p1/rr)*(y[i1,1]+y[i1,0])*(v[i1,1]-v[i1,0])- \
        #      (q1/rr)*(y[i1,1]+y[i1,0])*(R[i1,1]-R[i1,0])+f1(y[i1,0],v[i1,0])*t2
        #b[0] = (y[i1,0]+FD0)/(1+2.0*e210/rr)

        for i2 in range(1,N1):
            e21 = e1((y[i1,i2]+y[i1,i2-1])/2.00,(v[i1,i2]+v[i1,i2-1])/2.00)
            e22 = e1((y[i1,i2]+y[i1,i2+1])/2.00,(v[i1,i2]+v[i1,i2+1])/2.00)
            aa = e21/rr
            bb = e22/rr
            cc = aa+bb+1
            a[i2] = bb/(cc-aa*a[i2-1])

            r21 = (1.0/rr)*(y[i1,i2]+y[i1,i2-1])/2.
            r22 = (1.0/rr)*(y[i1,i2]+y[i1,i2+1])/2.

            L2v = p1*(r22*(v[i1,i2+1]-v[i1,i2]) - r21*(v[i1,i2]-v[i1,i2-1]))
            L2R = q1*(r22*(R[i1,i2+1]-R[i1,i2]) - r21*(R[i1,i2]-R[i1,i2-1]))

            d = y[i1,i2] + f1(y[i1,i2],v[i1,i2])*t2 - L2v - L2R
            b[i2]=(aa*b[i2-1]+d)/(cc-aa*a[i2-1])
        y[i1,N1]=0.
        #e22n = e1((y[i1,N1]+y[i1,N1-1])/2.00,(v[i1,N1]+v[i1,N1-1])/2.00)
        #FDn = p1*(y[i1,N1]+y[i1,N1-1])*(v[i1,N1]-v[i1,N1-1])/2.0 + \
        #      q1*(y[i1,N1]+y[i1,N1-1])*(R[i1,N1]-R[i1,N1-1])/2.0 + \
        #      f1(y[i1,N1],v[i1,N1])*hh/4.0
        #y[i1,N1]=(e22n*b[N1-1] + rr*y[i1,N1]/2.0 + FDn)/(e22n*(1-a[N1-1])+rr/2.0)

        for ii in range(1,N1+1):
            i2=N1-ii
            y[i1,i2] = a[i2]*y[i1,i2+1]+b[i2]

        for i2 in range(0,N1+1):
            if y[i1,i2]<0: y[i1,i2]=0.0

# v[k+1] to x2
        #e210 = e2((y[i1,1]+y[i1,0])/2.00,(v[i1,1]+v[i1,0])/2.00)
        #a[0] = e210/(e210+rr/2.0)
        #FD0 = (-p2/rr)*(v[i1,1]+v[i1,0])*(y[i1,1]-y[i1,0])- \
        #      (q2/rr)*(v[i1,1]+v[i1,0])*(R[i1,1]-R[i1,0])+f2(y[i1,0],v[i1,0])*t2
        #b[0] = (v[i1,0]+FD0)/(1+2.0*e210/rr)

        for i2 in range(1,N1):
            e21=e2((y[i1,i2]+y[i1,i2-1])/2.00,(v[i1,i2]+v[i1,i2-1])/2.00)
            e22=e2((y[i1,i2]+y[i1,i2+1])/2.00,(v[i1,i2]+v[i1,i2+1])/2.00)
            aa = e21/rr
            bb = e22/rr
            cc = aa+bb+1
            a[i2] = bb/(cc-aa*a[i2-1])

            r21 = (1.0/rr)*(v[i1,i2]+v[i1,i2-1])/2.
            r22 = (1.0/rr)*(v[i1,i2]+v[i1,i2+1])/2.

            L2y = p2*(r22*(y[i1,i2+1]-y[i1,i2])-r21*(y[i1,i2]-y[i1,i2-1]))
            L2R = q2*(r22*(R[i1,i2+1]-R[i1,i2])-r21*(R[i1,i2]-R[i1,i2-1]))

            d = v[i1,i2] + f2(y[i1,i2],v[i1,i2])*t2 - L2y - L2R
            b[i2]=(aa*b[i2-1]+d)/(cc-aa*a[i2-1])
        v[i1,N1]=0.
        #e22n = e2((y[i1,N1]+y[i1,N1-1])/2.00,(v[i1,N1]+v[i1,N1-1])/2.00)
        #FDn = p2*(v[i1,N1]+v[i1,N1-1])*(y[i1,N1]-y[i1,N1-1])/2.0 + \
        #      q2*(v[i1,N1]+v[i1,N1-1])*(R[i1,N1]-R[i1,N1-1])/2.0 + \
        #      f2(y[i1,N1],v[i1,N1])*hh/4.0
        #v[i1,N1]=(e22n*b[N1-1] + rr*v[i1,N1]/2.0 + FDn)/(e22n*(1-a[N1-1])+rr/2.0)

        for ii in range(1,N1+1):
            i2=N1-ii
            v[i1,i2] = a[i2]*v[i1,i2+1]+b[i2]

        for i2 in range(0,N1+1):
            if v[i1,i2]<0: v[i1,i2]=0.0
#graphics
    plt.clf()
    x1 = np.linspace(0., l, N1+1)
    x2 = np.linspace(0., l, N1+1)
    #fig = plt.figure()
    ax = Axes3D(fig, auto_add_to_figure=False)
    fig.add_axes(ax)
    X1, X2 = np.meshgrid(x1, x2)
    plt.xlabel('X')
    plt.ylabel('Y')
    ax.plot_surface(X1, X2, y, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap='Blues')
    ax.plot_surface(X1, X2, v, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap='BuGn')
    ax.plot_wireframe(X1, X2, y, rstride=1, cstride=1)
    #plt.contourf(XX1, XX2, y, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
    #plt.colorbar()
    #plt.show()
    #plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.01)

plt.ioff()
fig = plt.figure()
#ax = Axes3D(fig)
x1 = np.linspace(0., l, N1+1)
x2 = np.linspace(0., l, N1+1)
X1,X2 = np.meshgrid(x1, x2)
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
#ax.plot_surface(X1, X2, y, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap='Blues')
#ax.plot_surface(X1, X2, v, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap='BuGn')

          #Liniya urovnya ('ax' turn off before activation)

g = np.linspace(0., 2.0, 21)
plt.clabel(plt.contour(x1,x2,y,g,colors='gray'), inline=True, fontsize=8)
plt.contourf(x1,x2,y,g,cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
#plt.clabel(plt.contour(x1,x2,v,g,colors='gray'), inline=True, fontsize=8)
#plt.contourf(x1,x2,v,g,cmap=plt.cm.BuGn)
plt.colorbar()

plt.show()
#plt.show()
f1 = open('rezy.txt','w')
for i in range(0,N1+1):
    for j in range(0,N1+1):
        f1.write("%f\n" % y[i,j])
f1.close()
f2 = open('rezv.txt','w')
for i in range(0,N1+1):
    for j in range(0,N1+1):
        f2.write("%f\n" % v[i,j])
    f2.write("\n") 
f2.close()

dt = time.perf_counter() - tst
print(f"N2 = {N2}, N1 = {N1}, time solution = {dt:1.3e}, h = {h:1.3e}")
```

[image: -]

Comment: Спасибо только, вот у меня теперь на это ругается ax = Axes3D(fig, auto_add_to_figure=False)                               line 996, in update
    raise AttributeError(f"{type(self).__name__!r} object "
AttributeError: 'Axes3D' object has no property 'auto_add_to_figure'

Comment: @Gltockus Можете попробовать без него. У меня без него работает, но пишет `test.py:276: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Axes3D(fig) adding itself to the figure is deprecated since 3.4. Pass the keyword argument auto_add_to_figure=False and use fig.add_axes(ax) to suppress this warning. The default value of auto_add_to_figure will change to False in mpl3.5 and True values will no longer work in 3.6.  This is consistent with other Axes classes.
  ax = Axes3D(fig)`. Либо, наверное, надо обновить модуль.

Comment: а можно узнать что именно вы изменили?

Comment: @Gltockus Выкинул `pylab` и везде заменил его на `plt`, `clock()` заменил на `perf_counter()`, вынес создание `figure()` из тела цикла, добавил `pause()` для отрисовки. Собственно, из значимого это всё. Или [вот наглядное сравнение](https://editor.mergely.com/rvdsiF2l/) изменений.